# removing xml nodes using xslt but original XML namespace sand header should be retained

Tags: xslt-2.0

i checked the example in this link but it works for solution other way around , removees the nodes of the ID that i passed on to.

[Removing XML Nodes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152519/removing-xml-nodes-using-xslt)?

For example

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="example.lessson.1:v3"  >
    <dt:Header>     
        <dt:MessageId>12121212121212121</dt:MessageId>
        <dt:Timestamp>2013-01-01T00:00:00</dt:Timestamp>
        <dt:MessageType>2</dt:MessageType>
    </dt:Header>
<dt:Body >
<Rowsets>
<Rowset> 
    <Row>
        <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
         <LastName>David</LastName>
         <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
         <ID>111111<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>David</FirstName>
        <LastName>Michael</LastName>
        <Phone>01234567890</Phone>
        <ID>222222<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>Yang</FirstName>
        <LastName>Christina</LastName>
        <Phone>2345678901</Phone>
        <ID>333333<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>Grey</FirstName>
        <LastName>Meredith</LastName>
        <Phone>3456789012</Phone>
        <ID>4444444<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>David</FirstName>
        <LastName>Shepherd</LastName>
        <Phone>5678901234</Phone>
        <ID>5555555<ID>
    </Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
</body>
```

I need to run an XSLt that will use the ID i pass and create a new xml with only that node and header and other body tags retained
example if i pass 111111,222222,333333 as the input the output should be

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="example.lessson.1:v3"  >

    <dt:Header>     
        <dt:MessageId>12121212121212121</dt:MessageId>
        <dt:Timestamp>2013-01-01T00:00:00</dt:Timestamp>
        <dt:MessageType>2</dt:MessageType>
    </dt:Header>
<dt:Body >
<Rowsets>
<Rowset> 
    <Row>
        <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
         <LastName>David</LastName>
         <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
         <ID>111111<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>David</FirstName>
        <LastName>Michael</LastName>
        <Phone>01234567890</Phone>
        <ID>222222<ID>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <FirstName>Yang</FirstName>
        <LastName>Christina</LastName>
        <Phone>2345678901</Phone<ID>333333<ID>
    </Row> 
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter and compare the ID:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="ids">111111,222222,333333</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="id-sequence" select="tokenize($ids, '\s*,\s*')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[not(ID = $id-sequence)]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGF.