# Executing Ant 'replaceregexp' OK my local machine, but does not work on Microsoft VSTS

Tags: regex, xml, ant, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Looking for some help with Ant, and specifically the 'replaceregexp' method. Grateful for any and all advice.

**Problem**

We are using Ant to deploy XML files, and need to remove certain lines of XML before deploying. We are using Microsoft VSTS as our deployment tool.

We need Ant to scan through a number of files, and delete certain rows. Here is a small example of the source we need to analyse and delete:

```
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>   
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>CaseTriggerHandler</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

In this example, we want to find and delete this section of XML:

```
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

We are using 'replaceregexp' in Ant to do this. Here is the Ant code we have written to do this:

```
<replaceregexp match="&lt;classAccesses&gt;\n(.*?)&lt;apexClass&gt;CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test&lt;\/apexClass&gt;\n(.*?)&lt;enabled&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/enabled&gt;\n(.*?)&lt;\/classAccesses&gt;" replace="" flags="gm" byline="false">    
                      <fileset dir="${src.dir}/profiles" includes="**/*.profile" />
                    </replaceregexp>
```

This works fine when I run it on my Mac via Terminal, but when I attempt to run this on VSTS, it does not do the find/replace. Here are the debug logs for each:

**My Mac Debug statement**

```
[replaceregexp] Replacing pattern '<classAccesses>\n(.*?)<apexClass>CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test<\/apexClass>\n(.*?)<enabled>(.*?)<\/enabled>\n(.*?)<\/classAccesses>' with '' in '/Users/david.morris/DevWorkspace/R_Salesforce_Amey/src/profiles/FSL Mobile User.profile' with flags: 'gm'.
[replaceregexp] Found match; substituting
[replaceregexp] File has changed; saving the updated file
```

**VSTS Debug statement**

```
fileset: Setup scanner in dir d:\a\1\s\src\profiles with patternSet{ includes: [**/*.profile] excludes: [] }
 Replacing pattern '<classAccesses>\n(.*?)<apexClass>CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test<\/apexClass>\n(.*?)<enabled>(.*?)<\/enabled>\n(.*?)<\/classAccesses>' with '' in 'd:\a\1\s\src\profiles\AAD JIT Provisioning.profile' with flags: 'gm'.
 No change made
```

**Questions**

1. Can anyone see any reason why my Regex might work on my local machine, but not on VSTS?
2. Are there any other ways that are more fool-proof to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check if the line endings are different in the file in VSTS. I haven't used VSTS myself, but I do know that Windows uses `\r\n` for its line endings, whereas Linux and OSX simply use `\n`. If this file is being checked out via Git, the line endings might be getting changed to match the detected OS.

Comment: Also, a good way to avoid this problem is to use Ant's built in property `${line.separator}` which will match whatever the system is using for line endings. Don't worry about the fact that it contains special regex characters; Ant resolves properties first before evaluating the pattern.

Comment: Consider using [xslt](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) to filter xml rather than regular expressions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152519/removing-xml-nodes-using-xslt for an example.

Comment: Thank you kindly both for the feedback and support. An answer was proposed below that has removed the \n, so it must have been something to do with that as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code instead:

```
&lt;classAccesses&gt;.*&#10;.*&lt;apexClass&gt;CaseEntitlementMilestoneCalc_Test&lt;\/apexClass&gt;.*&#10;.*&lt;enabled&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/enabled&gt;.*&#10;.*&lt;\/classAccesses&gt;
```

Comment: Yes thank you that works!!! For my understanding, the key is to use &#10 instead of \n right?