# Can I get the parent nodes to copy with the child node using xslt?

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

I am trying to include parent nodes of the node I am copying.

Here is the sample file:

```
    <A>
       <B>
          <C1>Text Value</C1> 
          <C2></C2>
          <C3></C3>
          <C4></C4>
      </B>
   </A>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 <A>
    <B>
       <C1>Text Value</C1>
    </B>
</A>
```

Here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  
  
 <xsl:template match="/A/B/C1">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/A/B/C1"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, my output does not show the parent nodes.

Edit:
C1 will always have the same Xpath.  I would also like to include the Text of the node.

Comment: What do you mean "run the xslt twice on it and get different results"? An XSLT is a deterministic transform, given the input. If you don't change the input, and you don't change the XSL, then the result should _always_ be the same. What you're showing is just "the original file, with `C2` removed", in which case https://stackoverflow.com/a/12152983/740553 should already address that need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I might have thrown you off. That sentence was a mistake, I removed it.

Comment: But the code you're showing still just effects "removing C2", so the SO answer I linked to in my comment above should still address that.

Comment: In reference to  stackoverflow.com/a/12152983/740553: I am not trying to delete C2, I am trying to copy C1.  In the real file there are many other elements.  I don't want to delete each node manually.

Comment: Then update your post so that you clearly explain what exactly you need to do, because right now the xml you're showing and the text you've written do not match the comment you wrote. [be more detailed than you think you need to be](/help/how-to-ask), because you're talking to complete strangers: we only know what you tell us in your post =)

Comment: I did write copy the node, however, the question is updated so that the other answer won't work.

Comment: Now you're still just showing code that strongly implies you just want to keep C1, and throw away anything after it. Please explain _in text_ in your post what it is you really need to do. Are there multiple `C1` children? Are they all at the start? Interspersed amongst other child nodes? Is there only one? Can it be at the end of the childnodes array? etc. Seriously: [be far more detailed than you'd think you need to be](/help/how-to-ask). There are tons of ways to do simple things in XSL, and the code you show atm is simple code. So if your case is not simple, explain what makes it hard.

Comment: The xml I am using has hundreds of nodes.  I don't want to delete each one manually.  I just want to keep/copy a few.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234139/discussion-between-gc-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to produce the result you show:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[descendant-or-self::C1] | C1/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> Edit: C1 will always have the same Xpath.

Well, then here's another:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <A>
        <B>
            <xsl:copy-of select="A/B/C1"/>    
        </B>
    </A>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Very good answer.  It seems to work like expected.  However, is there a way to tweak it to include the node value.

Comment: Like <C1>Text Value</C1> rather than <C1></C1>.

Comment: I ended up doing it the second way listed.